# Modificar DisplayExpr

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, devexpress

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
groupItems.AddSimpleFor(m => m.Bcx_codigo).CssClass("lbcod")
                        .Editor(e => e.SelectBox().Width("300px")
                        .DataSource(ContaBancariaController.ListaBancosBuscados)
                        .DisplayExpr("Ban_Nome")
                        .ValueExpr("Bcx_codigo")
                        .ID("ibcod"));;
```

Ele resulta em :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Onde eu escolho o que aparece para mim é no `DisplayExpr`, estou correto?, gostaria de modificar o `DisplayExpr` para não exibir apenas o `Ban_Nome`, mas também um outro campo chamado `Bcx_agencia`

Queria algo como `("Ban_Nome" + , + "Bcx_agencia")`, como posso alterar o `DisplayExpr` para fazer isso? e outra duvida, o `ValueExpr` eu escolho o dado que quero enviar, estou correto?

Comment: viu minha resposta?

Comment: Desculpe a demora, estou vendo agora

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode manipular o seu `DataSource` para popular o componente com as informações que deseja.

```
groupItems
    .AddSimpleFor(m => m.Bcx_codigo)
    .CssClass("lbcod")
    .Editor(e => e.SelectBox().Width("300px")
    .DataSource(ContaBancariaController.ListaBancosBuscados
                .Select(x => 
                        new { x.Bcx_codigo, 
                              Display = $"{x.Ban_Nome} - {x.Bcx_Agencia}"
                            }
                        ).ToList())
    .DisplayExpr("Display")
    .ValueExpr("Bcx_codigo")
    .ID("ibcod");
```

Comment: Era exatamente isso que eu queria, muito obrigado

Comment: Só uma duvida, o o ValueExpr eu escolho o dado que quero enviar para o Bcx_codigo, estou certo?

Comment: Isso, assim como para o `Display`, você pode colocar o que quiser em uma propriedade e mapear no `ValueExpr()`.

Comment: Ok, entendi, obrigado

Comment: Se não for pedir muito, fiz uma outra pergunta, creio que você pode me ajudar, se der da uma olhada por favor: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/361247/adicionar-checkbox-ao-campo-do-datagrid