# Adicionar CheckBox ao campo do DataGrid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, devexpress

Tenho um `DataGrid` e estou querendo colocar em um campo um `CheckBox`, estava pesquisando e parece que com o `.EditorOptions()` é possível fazer isso, mas não sei como, apenas passando `CheckBox` como parâmetro, n funciona, e eu gostaria que esse campo envie **S** ou **N** para selecionado ou nao selecionado respectivamente

Meu código:

```
@(Html.DevExtreme().DataGrid<CobrancaViewModel>().ID("gridContainer")
    .ColumnAutoWidth(true)
    .Height(200)
    .Width(650)
    .ShowBorders(true)
    .Paging(paging => paging.Enabled(false))
    .Editing(editing =>
        {
            editing.Mode(DevExtreme.AspNet.Mvc.GridEditMode.Row);
            editing.AllowAdding(true);
            editing.AllowDeleting(true);
            editing.AllowUpdating(true);
    })
    .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.AddFor(m => m.CbaCob_carteira);
            columns.AddFor(m => m.CbaCob_variacao);
            columns.AddFor(m => m.CbaCob_especie);
            columns.AddFor(m => m.CbaCob_EspecieDocumento);
            columns.AddFor(m => m.CbaCob_Aceite);
            columns.AddFor(m => m.CbaCob_Aceite); //Gostaria de adicionar a essa coluna  o CheckBox                                                                                 
            columns.AddFor(m => m.CbaCob_convenio);
            columns.AddFor(m => m.CbaCob_SistemaCobranca);
            columns.AddFor(m => m.CbaCob_MensagemLocalPag);
    })
    .DataSource(AgenciaController.ListaContatos)
    .OnContentReady("pegarDadosGrid")
 )
```

Pra quem não entendeu: eu tenho um grid e vários campos a serem preenchidos dentro do grid, e preciso que um desses campo seja um campo de seleção, exemplo na imagem a seguir :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: quais são os overloads do `columns.AddFor()`?

Comment: você quer mostrar um Checkbox ou S/N ?

Comment: Desculpe, mas não sei responder essa pergunta

Comment: Quero mostrar o Checkbox

Comment: quando você escreve `columns.AddFor(m => m.CbaCob_Aceite` e adiciona uma `,` ele apresenta outros construtores com mais parâmetros?

Comment: Sim, inclusive consigo escrever ´CheckBox()´ Porém ele diz que não é válido no contexto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver da seguinte maneira :

```
columns.AddFor(m => m.CbaCob_Aceite).DataType(GridColumnDataType.Boolean);
```

E fiz um tratamento na controller:

```
foreach (var lista in ListaCobranca)
                {
                    lista.CbaCob_Aceite = lista.CbaCob_Aceite.Equals("true") ? "S" : "N";
}
```